# Creating non-print PDF's from MS Office

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office

Is there an easy way to create a PDF in MS Office (Word / Excel) that has the no-print flag set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.saveaswwf.com/en/

I use it at work and it's awesome.

Comment: You're welcome ^_^

Opens in Adobe Reader, Foxit PDF Reader etc. no problems.